# Functionality of Swing ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

A quick question about the example code in the [JavaDoc for `javax.swing.ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html):

I'm a little surprised, that in the example, the `ListCellRenderer` is implemented by a  class that extends `JLabel` and that the `getListCellRendererComponent(...)`-method simply returns `this`. It looks like there is only one instance of a `JLabel` around then, even for a list containing more than one element.

Usually, I would then expect that when the `setText(...)` method is called inside `getListCellRendererComponent(...)` for the second item in the list, it changes the label of the already existing first item in the list. Or, actually, it probably shouldn't even be possible for the list to use the same `JLabel`-instance twice (or more times), once for each item in the list.

Now, I've come up with two possible ways to resolve this and was wondering which one (if any) is actually happening:

- Does `JList` somehow create new instances of the provided `ListCellRenderer` for each list item?
- Or does it use the component returned by `getListCellRendererComponent(...)` only to invoke its `paint(...)` method on the list's canvas rather than actually adding this component to some panel?

Comment: ListCellRenderer is responsible for decorating virtual painting to JList, JComboBox, renderer is invoked from all mouse and key events, notifiers implemented in concrete API Q: `Does JList somehow ... `---> yes but answer is not `Or does it use the ... `---> - yes painting only virtual JComponents as the Item into JLists rectangles

Comment: @mKorbel: Now I'm confused. ;) "painting only virtual JComponents as the Item into JLists rectangles" is what I meant in "Or does it use the...". But in the sentence before you write that that one is the wrong one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `JList` renders itself it asks the `ListModel` for the elements it should display.
For each element it calls the `javax.swing.ListCellRenderer` to provide a render component. Then it paints the component. That's all. A render component is not bound to an element's state that it renders.

The javadoc of `ListCellRenderer` says:

> Identifies components that can be used as "rubber stamps" 
>       to paint the cells in a `JList`.

So your second assumption is right.

A look at `javax.swing.plaf.BasicListUI` shows it:

```
protected void paintCell(Graphics g, int row, Rectangle rowBounds,
        ListCellRenderer cellRenderer, ListModel dataModel,
        ListSelectionModel selModel, int leadIndex) {
    Object value = dataModel.getElementAt(row);
    boolean cellHasFocus = list.hasFocus() && (row == leadIndex);
    boolean isSelected = selModel.isSelectedIndex(row);

    Component rendererComponent = cellRenderer
            .getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, row, isSelected,
                    cellHasFocus);

    int cx = rowBounds.x;
    int cy = rowBounds.y;
    int cw = rowBounds.width;
    int ch = rowBounds.height;

    if (isFileList) {
        // Shrink renderer to preferred size. This is mostly used on Windows
        // where selection is only shown around the file name, instead of
        // across the whole list cell.
        int w = Math
                .min(cw, rendererComponent.getPreferredSize().width + 4);
        if (!isLeftToRight) {
            cx += (cw - w);
        }
        cw = w;
    }

    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, rendererComponent, list, cx, cy, cw, ch,
            true);
}
```

Comment: So it does not actually add the component returned by the ListCellRenderer to some panel. It only uses it's paint method?

Comment: Yes it does. I updated the answer. The BasicListUI extends a ListUI which is the UI for a JList ( JList.getUI() ).

Comment: Maybe it's useful to add an excerpt of the `CellRendererPane` source as well, showing that `rendererPane.paintComponent(...)` only calls `rendererComponent.paint(...)`, but from the name and arguments of the function, it's technically already obvious. :) Thanks! +1, v´